# How to know which values are different from the existing in the database given a request.POST

Tags: python, django

I have this view (truncated) to edit existing `Projects`:

```
def edit_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_to_edit = Project.objects.get(pk=request.POST['project_id'])
        form = CreateNewProjectForm(request.POST, instance=project_to_edit)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('project_page')
        else:
            return redirect('edit_project')
    return redirect('index')
```

It works great, everything as expected but I would like to somehow know which fields are being updated/modified in the most pythonic way.

The reason I want to know which fields are modified is to save a record in my AuditHistory model for each modified field.

Ideally I would like to add the following code after the `form.save()` line:

```
username = None
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user = request.user
if user:
    #for each modified field, save a row into AuditHistory
    audit_history_entry = AuditHistory(user=user, event="Edit Project", changed_field="?", old_value="?", new_value="?")
    audit_history_entry.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`FieldTracker`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker) is what you need.

All you need to use is add this to your model:

```py
tracker = FieldTracker()
```

You can track if field changed:

```py
>>> a = Post.objects.create(title='First Post')
>>> a.title = 'Welcome'
>>> a.tracker.has_changed('title')
True
>>> a.tracker.has_changed('body')
False
```

Obtain all changed fields:

```py
>>> a = Post.objects.create(title='First Post')
>>> a.title = 'Welcome'
>>> a.body = 'First post!'
>>> a.tracker.changed()
{'title': 'First Post', 'body': ''}
```

And see what was the previous value:

```py
>>> a = Post.objects.create(title='First Post')
>>> a.title = 'Welcome'
>>> a.tracker.previous('title')
u'First Post'
```

`FieldTracker` requires `django-model-utils` which could be installed with `pip`:

```
pip install django-model-utils
```

Comment: Sounds promising, however I have to install new dependencies, and check manually each field `a.tracker.has_changed('n_fields')` which is something I wanted to avoid...especially since I will need it for several models and some have more than 100 fields :(

Comment: @Cheknov you can iterate all needed fields. `MyModel._meta.get_fields()` or you can implement it using custom list.

Comment: @Cheknov also you can iterate all `my_model.tracker.changed()` in combination with `my_model.tracker.previous('title')`, so you won't need to check each field manually.